# Use variables as parameters

Tags: java

I have a class

```
public class Coordinates {
   public int x,y,z;

   public Coordinates (x, y, z) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.z = z;
   }
}
```

In another class' method I want to get access on the coordinates, but I have to do the same long code for each coordinate `x`,`y` and `z`. Is there a way to use variables for the parameters such as :

```
Coordinates coords0 = new Coordinates(1, 2, 3);
Coordinates coords1 = new Coordinates(4, 1, 3);
Coordinates coords2 = new Coordinates(5, 1, 3);
Coordinates coords3 = new Coordinates(1, 1, 3);
Coordinates coords4 = new Coordinates(1, 2, 0);
Set<Coordinates> set = new HashSet<Coordinates>();
set.add(coords0);
set.add(coords1);
set.add(coords2);
set.add(coords3);
set.add(coords4);
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String param = "";
    if(i == 0) param = "x";
    if(i == 1) param = "y";
    if(i == 2) param = "z";
    Iterator<Coordinates> it = set.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
       Coordinates currentCoords = it.next();
       sum += currentCoords.param;
    }
}
```

This does not work obviously, but is there a way to achieve something similar to this ?

Comment: Why the `i==0` 3 times? Surely all but the last is redundant?

Comment: *"is there a way to achieve something similar to this ?"* No. Well, yes, using reflection, but don't do that. If you want to do some complex code on `x`, `y`, and `z`, write that code in a method, then call it 3 times, e.g. `doComplex(coords.x); doComplex(coords.y); doComplex(coords.z);`.

Comment: How about `longCode(coordinates.x); longCode(coordinates.y); longCode(coordinates.z);` Could you show what the "long code" is?

Comment: that was a typo, I edited it @AndyTurner

Comment: I'm confused.  What are you trying to accomplish here, really?  Every field in `Coordinates` is *public*, so you could refer to it by `coords.x`, `coords.y`, `coords.z` if you really wanted to.

Comment: I am not sure if the whole 'long code' would help you. It involves a lot of other stuff besides my problem.
I have to apply the `x`, `y` and `z` to a whole set of Coordinates in several loops, thats why I can not just put `coords.x` I just sumplified my problem

Comment: You simplified it so well that we don't understand what the actual problem might be.

Comment: I edited it again. Should come closer now. Is it better now to understand my actual problem ? @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the problem is that you must apply the same code to a *collection* of coordinates, and this same code must be done for all the x of the coordinates, then to all the y of the coordinates, then for all the z of the coordinates.

So you probably need a method looking like this:

```
private void complexCode(Collection<Coordinates> collection, ToIntFunction<Coordinates> axisAccessor) {
   // ...
   for (Coordinates c : collection) {
       int axis = axisAccessor.applyAsInt(c);
       //...
   }
   // ...
}
```

You would then call your function three times using

```
complexCode(collection, coordinates -> coordinates.x);
complexCode(collection, coordinates -> coordinates.y);
complexCode(collection, coordinates -> coordinates.z);
```

Comment: That is exactly it!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your current attempt is pretty close, only you don't need a `param` variable, `println` (and based on a comment, eliminate the `i` value). Like,

```
Coordinates coords = new Coordinates(1, 2, 3);
System.out.println("Coordinate x is " + coords.x);
System.out.println("Coordinate y is " + coords.y);
System.out.println("Coordinate z is " + coords.z);
```

**or** format it a little differently, and override `toString()` in `Coordinates`. Oh, and fix the constructor.

```
public class Coordinates {
    public int x, y, z;

    public Coordinates(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("x=%d, y=%d, z=%d", x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Then you could `print` it like

```
Coordinates coords = new Coordinates(1, 2, 3);
System.out.println("Coordinate " + coords);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want to print the coordinates. This was meant to represent my problem simply. I need to apply it to a whole set of Coordinates in a loop

Comment: @shmosel Nice one. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is a getter method. It is a good idea to create setter methods as well. Heres what they look like for x. You'll need to make similar methods for y and z.

```
public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public void setX(int newX){
    x = newX;
}
```

you create these in your Coordinates class then from your other class you can do

```
if(i == 0) param = coords.getX();
```

Comment: That'd be the more conventional way to go about it if each field weren't public...That's not saying this is a wrong answer.  This would be correct if we could get a better grip on what the OP is asking.

Comment: Yeah, this would work, but I can not manipulate the Coordinates class unfortunately

Comment: *It is a good idea to create setter methods as well*: actually, no. Making such a class immutable would be a much better idea.

Comment: I didn't even realize x, y, and z were public. in that case just refer to them by `coords.x`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use reflection like this:

```
int paramInt = Coordinates.class.getField(param).getInt(coords);
System.out.println("Coordinate "+param+" is "+paramInt);
```

Don't.